# Can I change Input Data every start doWork() in PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder

Tags: android, worker

Can I setInputData([someDataChangeEveryWorkerStart])

```
val uploadWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>((1, TimeUnit.HOURS))
    .setInputData(imageData)
    .build()
```

which imageData change every 1 hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `Worker` when you finish method `doWork` you should `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork` with new data and using `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE` to replace the current worker

```
val uploadWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>((1, TimeUnit.HOURS))
    .setInputData(newImageData)
    .build()
WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        “YourWorkerTag”,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        uploadWorkRequest)
```